# update_meta_user difference in i:1 and b:1, how to write b:1

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

This code leads to wp_cababilities being written to the database but with an i:1 in front.

```
if( $new_roles === 'administrator' ) {
    $capabilities = array ("administrator",'activate_plugins','delete_others_pages','delete_others_posts','delete_pages','delete_plugins','delete_posts','delete_private_pages','delete_private_posts','delete_published_pages','delete_published_posts','edit_dashboard','edit_files','edit_others_pages','edit_others_posts','edit_pages','edit_posts','edit_private_pages','edit_private_posts','edit_published_pages','edit_published_posts','edit_theme_options','export','import','list_users','manage_categories','manage_links','manage_options','moderate_comments','promote_users','publish_pages','publish_posts','read_private_pages','read_private_posts','read','remove_users','switch_themes','upload_files','create_product');
    $user->set_role('administrator');
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_capabilities', $capabilities );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_user_level', 10 );
}
```

This is what is placed in the database:

```
a:39:i:0;s:13:"administrator";i:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";i:2;s:19:"delete_others_pages";i:3;s:19:"delete_others_posts";i:4;s:12:"delete_pages";i:5;s:14:"delete_plugins";i:6;s:12:"delete_posts";i:7;s:20:"delete_private_pages";i:8;s:20:"delete_private_posts";i:9;s:22:"delete_published_pages";i:10;s:22:"delete_published_posts";i:11;s:14:"edit_dashboard";i:12;s:10:"edit_files";i:13;s:17:"edit_others_pages";i:14;s:17:"edit_others_posts";i:15;s:10:"edit_pages";i:16;s:10:"edit_posts";i:17;s:18:"edit_private_pages";i:18;s:18:"edit_private_posts";i:19;s:20:"edit_published_pages";i:20;s:20:"edit_published_posts";i:21;s:18:"edit_theme_options";i:22;s:6:"export";i:23;s:6:"import";i:24;s:10:"list_users";i:25;s:17:"manage_categories";i:26;s:12:"manage_links";i:27;s:14:"manage_options";i:28;s:17:"moderate_comments";i:29;s:13:"promote_users";i:30;s:13:"publish_pages";i:31;s:13:"publish_posts";i:32;s:18:"read_private_pages";i:33;s:18:"read_private_posts";i:34;s:4:"read";i:35;s:12:"remove_users";i:36;s:13:"switch_themes";i:37;s:12:"upload_files";i:38;s:14:"create_product";}
```

These capabilities do not work for that user.

A simple copy/paste of the following into the database **gives the user the capabilities**

```
a:27:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:11:"delete_post";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;}
```

**What is the difference between the i:1 and b:1 ? How can I get the update_meta_user to add the b:1?**

I cannot find a document but curious if this is i for integer and b for boolean. In which case, how can I get this code to update the wp_cabailities database field?

Comment: Yes this is integer and boolean. See the [docs for serialize() in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Comment: Thank you for the link. Now, how do I get update_user_meta to be boolean then?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Change the capabilities of a role? Add a new role? User Levels have been deprecated in WordPess>=3.0

Comment: Thanks. I've been fussing for weeks now. I'm down to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134989/how-to-properly-modify-get-userdata-in-plugin-to-get-roles-to-update-in-database -- in which I change the name of the function from get_userdata to get_xf_userdata and writing to the database fails.  Changing code to update_user_meta adds the capabalities but as an integer (now know this!). Capabilities need to be written as boolean to work (now know this!).

Answer (score 0):

Your first serialized string is broken. I can't spot why but you should not be trying to manipulate capabilities manually. You already have a user object. Use it.

```
if( $new_roles === 'administrator' ) {
  $capabilities = array ("administrator",'activate_plugins','delete_others_pages','delete_others_posts','delete_pages','delete_plugins','delete_posts','delete_private_pages','delete_private_posts','delete_published_pages','delete_published_posts','edit_dashboard','edit_files','edit_others_pages','edit_others_posts','edit_pages','edit_posts','edit_private_pages','edit_private_posts','edit_published_pages','edit_published_posts','edit_theme_options','export','import','list_users','manage_categories','manage_links','manage_options','moderate_comments','promote_users','publish_pages','publish_posts','read_private_pages','read_private_posts','read','remove_users','switch_themes','upload_files','create_product');
  $user->set_role('administrator');
  foreach ($capabilities as $cap) {
    $user->add_cap($cap);
  }
}
```

Untested but that should work. However, you should only need to explicitly add the capabilities not already implied by the role. You could make that capability array significantly shorter.

Comment: I've tried that code many times. When the function is named get_userdata then it works. If I rename the function then writing to the database fails. I've yet to figure out why but now see update_user_meta is adding as an integer and not as I want. So I'm stuck. If I use get_userdata and modify it in the plugin then all capabilities for everyone is written. If I rename the function then I only get the current user but capabilities will not write.

Comment: This is where I'm stuck: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134989/how-to-properly-modify-get-userdata-in-plugin-to-get-roles-to-update-in-database and thought update_user_meta was the answer.

Comment: `get_userdata` ___does not appear___ anywhere in your question. It doesn't really matter how many times you've "tried that code" it is a still the wrong way to manipulate capabilities. Changes to the Core could easily break your implementation.

Comment: It is in the bottom. get_userdata is NOT core, right? It is pluggable. Look. You've posted several times very unhelpful things. I'm learning. You may help or not but if you look at the link I posted in my comment to you starting "This is where I'm stuck... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134989/how-to-properly-modify-get-userdata-in-plugin-to-get-roles-to-update-in-database